# ubuntu 14.04, xdmx, and the dreaded wrong authentication

Tags: 14.04, permissions, xdmx

I've started a quest for a multiheaded system with the following links:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOzRCBGDVaE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlcqkNRN-b8

http://mitros.org/p/xdmx-setup.html

The last link is the one I've been using to test because it offers some feedback and debugging while getting set up.

On the client machine I can SSH into the Host without issue.  When I enter:

```
export | grep DISPLAY
```

The prompt returns a reasonable string like "localhost:10.0"

when I enter this on the host machine:

```
Xdmx :1 +xinerama -display localhost:10.0
```

on the host machine this is returned:

```
(Fatal Error) dmx: dmxOpenDisplay: Unable to open display localhost:10.0
```

on the client machine this is displayed in the terminal window:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
```

I've googled a ton and the client side error is where I'm stuck.  I found this site http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication/

Going down the list of recomendations on that site (on the host and client machines that are identical laptops):
My hard drive has got almost nothing on it 61G of 72G available
I checked the ownership of /.Xauthority and I own it and have permission to read and write to it, I even ran chmod 0666 without luck to see if that changed anything.
The last instruction is `X11Forwarding yes is declared in the sshd_config file.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to where I should turn next or where I've gone wrong?

Loren`